# How to convert a *const pointer into a Vec to correctly drop it?

Tags: rust

After [asking](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3zeq3w/correct_way_to_use_an_arraylike_struct_with_box/) how I should go about freeing memory across the FFI boundary, someone on the Rust reddit suggested that rather than wrapping my structs in a `Box`, I could use `Vec::from_raw_parts` to construct a vector from the following struct, and that this could be safely dropped:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct Array {
    data: *const c_void,
    len: libc::size_t,
}
```

However, `from_raw_parts` seems to require `*mut _` data, so I'm not sure how to proceed…

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The very short answer is `self.data as *mut u8`. But, let's talk more details...

First, words of warning:

1. Do **not** use `Vec::from_raw_parts` unless the pointer came from a `Vec` originally. There is **no guarantee** that an arbitrary pointer will be compatible with a `Vec` and you are likely to create giant holes in your program if you proceed.
2. Do **not** free a pointer that you don't own. Doing so leads to *double frees*, which will blow other large holes in your program.
3. You **need** to know the *capacity* of the vector before you can reconstruct it. Your example struct only contains a `len`. This is only acceptable if the `len` and `capacity` are equal.

Now, let's see if I can follow my own rules...

```
extern crate libc;

use std::mem;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct Array {
    data: *const libc::c_void,
    len: libc::size_t,
}

// Note that both of these methods should probably be implementations
// of the `From` trait to allow them to participate in more places.
impl Array {
    fn from_vec(mut v: Vec<u8>) -> Array {
        v.shrink_to_fit(); // ensure capacity == size

        let a = Array {
            data: v.as_ptr() as *const libc::c_void,
            len: v.len(),
        };

        mem::forget(v);

        a
    }

    fn into_vec(self) -> Vec<u8> {
        unsafe { Vec::from_raw_parts(self.data as *mut u8, self.len, self.len) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let a = Array::from_vec(v);
    let v = a.into_vec();
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

Note that we don't have to do any explicit dropping of the `Vec` because the normal `Drop` implementation of `Vec` comes into play. We just have to make sure that we construct a `Vec` properly.