# How do I prevent a Rust program from free()ing a C bytes that it does not own

Tags: rust

libc has a function that returns a string that should not be free()d. The users current directory can be read from `/etc/passwd` but should not be free()d.  If I create a String from the pointer the program aborts nastily

```
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Obviously the code is unsafe.

```
let pw = libc::getpwnam(username.as_ptr() as *const i8);
let cd = (*pw).pw_dir;
let len = libc::strlen(cd);
builder.current_dir(String::from_raw_parts(cd as *mut u8, len, len));
```

I can `mem::forget(s)` the String but that leaks memory, at least length must be stored somewhere.  I just need to prevent freeing of the underlying raw bytes.  Project is a server so I cant ignore the leak.

Comment: Why are using C bindings to read passed? That is just as easily done in entirely safe Rust?

Comment: Is there a reason you would not use https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html ?

Comment: "I can mem::forget(s) the String but that leaks memory" obviously not because the string is not allocated.

Comment: `String::from_raw_parts` is incorrect, see its documentation. As harmic said, you should use `CStr`, as a start. (I’d also opt for `getpwnam_r`.) Remember to check for errors.

Comment: "The users current directory" – I'm not quite sure what you are looking for, but based on the code you may be looking for the current user's home directory. I recommend reading the `HOME` environment variable instead on Linux, or use [`dirs::home_dir()`](https://docs.rs/dirs/2.0.2/dirs/fn.home_dir.html) for a solution that also works on Windows.

Comment: @Stargateur are you suggesting simply mem::forget(s) would work and not leak?  Clearly it will no leak the string's data but will it leak nothing?  Where is the length of the string stored if it is not within the String?

Comment: @Sven I was also looking for pw_uid and pw_gid returned by the same call.

Comment: there can't be a leak there isn't an allocation. Read `getpwnam()` documentation.

Comment: the String itself is allocated, that contains the bytes data and the length, if you look in String it a struct with one member `vec: Vec<u8>, Vec` is a struct `buf: RawVec<T>, len: usize,`  there is memory allocated for the length in a String that need to be freed.

Comment: seems `slice::from_raw_parts` is the way to go,

Comment: no you all wrong

Comment: @teknopaul *there is memory allocated for the length in a String that need to be freed.* - this is not true, the length is stored directly in the string, it is not allocated on the heap. Rust `String` is guaranteed to hold exactly three machine words: the pointer to the data, the length of the data, and the allocated capacity. Only the actual data needs to be freed explicitly (and won't be if you use `mem::forget`, the rest is automatically discarded as the `String` goes out of scope, even if you you use `mem::forget`.

Comment: Kinda annoying when stackoverflow closes a question pointing to a different solution to a different problem :)  Is there a way to contact @mcarton,  my question as phrased seems like it could be answered by `mem::forget(s)` other question cannot. I think when searching for "rust prevent free", this discussion is as valid or more so than discussions on ::from_raw_parts, which are specific to C Strings. Depending on why a user searches for  "rust prevent free", can we open this again and at least propose `mem::forget(s)`  as a possible answer?

Answer (score 5):

[`String::from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_raw_parts) is the incorrect function to use here. That function must only be called with pointer previously obtained from [`String::into_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.into_raw_parts) or equivalent, which is obviously not the case in your code, where the pointer comes from the C library and the memory it points to is not even dynamically allocated. When using an API marked unsafe, such as `from_raw_parts`, one should carefully review the documentation, which in this case marks the function as "highly unsafe", and precisely the contract that the caller must adhere to.

Instead, you should create an `&str` pointing into the data, either using [`slice::from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html) and [`str::from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html) or using the [`CStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html) type designed for that purpose. Once you have a `&str`, you should copy it into an owned string and call `builder.current_dir()` with that. Calling `builder.current_dir()` with the `&str` would compile, but would be unsafe, requiring you to prove that that function (and the functions it calls) never invoke `getpwnam`.

Here is an example:

```rust
let pw = libc::getpwnam(username.as_ptr() as *const i8);
let cd = (*pw).pw_dir;
let cd_string = CStr::from_ptr(cd).to_str().unwrap().to_owned();
builder.current_dir(&cd_string);
```

Note that this code is still unsound because `getpwnam` is not thread-safe. You should use [`getpwnam_r`](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.66/libc/fn.getpwnam_r.html) instead or, better yet, use a crate like [`dirs`](https://crates.io/crates/dirs) that [does all that](https://docs.rs/dirs/2.0.2/dirs/fn.home_dir.html) for you.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50376516/155423) deals with the same underlying issue, but with the goal of creating a `Vec`.

Comment: How is passing a reference to an owned string (`let cd_string = ...().to_owned()` .... `.current_dir(&cd_string)`) different than just passing `CStr::from_ptr(cd).to_str().unwrap()` ? Why do you consider it safer ?

Comment: @SvetlinZarev We have no idea what `current_dir` does. If it (or any of the functions it calls) happens to invoke `getpwnam` itself, the data the slice points to will change (or become completely invalid). That is not allowed in safe Rust. Copying the data into a new `String` prevents that, barring the issue with multiple threads, which can be fixed by switching to the reentrant variant of the call.